# Updating values in multi value dictionary from another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries, and I am looking for a way to update values in multi value dictionary IP_list, by checking value in dictionary ID_list. Basically I need to substitute an email string from IP_list by id value from ID_list.

`IP_list={'ip1': ['email1', 'string1'], 'ip2': ['email2', 'string2'],'ip3': ['email2', 'string3']}`

`ID_list={'email1': 'id1', 'email2': 'id2', 'email3': 'id3'}`

Expected output:
`{'ip1': ['id1', 'string1'], 'ip2': ['id2', 'string2'],'ip3': ['id2', 'string3']}`

or the ID value can be added on the end of specific key values as:
`{'ip1': ['email1','string1','id1'], 'ip2': ['email2','string2','id2'],'ip3': ['email2','string3','id2']}`

Can someone be of any help ?

Thanks
J.

Edit:I tried solution suggested by Roman it works on Python 2.7.5 with no problem, but it is giving me hard time to get it working on Python 2.6.6

@Roman, IP_list is created from MSSQL db by:

```
for row in results:
      IP_list[row.IP_address]= row.email, row.description
```

`print IP_list` will give this:
on Python 2.7.5 on my dev environment I will get :

```
{'IP': ('email1', 'description "info"'),'IP2': ('email2', 'description')}
```

On on production system with Python 2.6.6 I will get some values unicode

```
{'IP': (u'email1', u'description "info"'),'IP2': (u'email2', u'description')}
```

so I converted the unicode values to ascii, so there should be no problem.

ID_list is created from XML on output is same on both envinronments:

```
{'email1': 'id1', 'email2': 'id2', 'email3': 'id3'}
```

when I run the script on Python 2.7.5 it works fine, but on 2.6.6 it gives me this error

```
val[0] = ID_list.get(val[0], val[0])
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Python 2 or 3, or either?

Comment: according to the error you pasted, `val` is a tuple and you code should fail in any Python version.  Could you share definition and all the related code of this `val` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
for val in IP_list.itervalues():
    val[0] = ID_list.get(val[0], val[0])
```

If email from `IP_list` is missing in the `ID_list`, it won't be changed.

And now IP_list looks like:

```
{'ip2': ['id2', 'string2'], 'ip3': ['id2', 'string3'], 'ip1': ['id1', 'string1']}
```

Comment: wow, that was fast, thank you very much, that is what I was trying to do all day long, and you did that in 5 minutes.

Comment: Roman, can you help me with this one more time, this solution is not  working on Python 2.6.6. Which will be the version available on target machine, which I did not know earlier. Thanks J.

Comment: @user3043455 It should be working on Python 2.6.  Could you share the details?